# PrestaShop: Redirect to homepage if the product didn't exists

Tags: php, prestashop, redirect, prestashop-1.6

i'm trying to redirect page like this :

https://www.cdsoft.co.il/index.php?id_product=303915&controller=product&id_lang=1

i want that every page, with deleted id_product - will be redirected to my homepage:

which means : i want to redirect "https://www.cdsoft.co.il/index.php?id_product=XXX"

how to do it in the htaccess file ?

Comment: Need of htaccess or even via php ?

Comment: maybe via php...i dont how to do redirect via php..

Comment: I guess you can't do in `.htaccess` because Apache can't know if a product is removed or not. You have to do in the Product controller, like suggested by @Labradorcode

Answer (score 3):

I propose the @Labradorcode idea, but with the correct approach.
Make an ovverride of ProductController.php in `rootofps/override/controllers/front/ProductController.php`, so you have to create a new file in that directory (for rootofps I mean the install directory of PrestaShop), the content of that file is written below:

```
class ProductController extends ProductControllerCore {
    public function init(){
        FrontController::init();

        if ($id_product = (int)Tools::getValue('id_product')) {
            $this->product = new Product($id_product, true, $this->context->language->id, $this->context->shop->id);
        }

        if (!Validate::isLoadedObject($this->product)) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
            header('Status: 404 Not Found');
            header('Location: '.$this->context->link->getPageLink('index', array('id_product', Tools::getValue('id_product'))));
        } else {
            parent::init();
        }
    }
}
```

In this case the redirect works if the product is totally removed and not if is disabled.

After you have created the file delete this file `rootofps/cache/class_index.php`

Comment: thanks. now i'm getting this error :  public class ProductController extends ProductControllerCore { public function init(){ FrontController::init(); if ($id_product = (int)Tools::getValue('id_product')) { $this->product = new Product($id_product, true, $this->context->language->id, $this->context->shop->id); }

Comment: if (!Validate::isLoadedObject($this->product)) { header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'); header('Status: 404 Not Found'); header('Location: '.$this->context->link->getPageLink('index', array('id_product', Tools::getValue('id_product')))); } else { parent::init(); } } } 
Fatal error: Class 'ProductController' not found in /..../classes/controller/Controller.php on line 134

Comment: Have you followed the 'instructions'? Which version of prestashop do you have?

Comment: im using 1.6.1.4. i've add the ProductController.php to the override/controller/front/ , and deleted the class_index.php

Comment: I'm sorry, remove public from class declaration. My bad. 
PS: the correct path is override/controller`s`/front, controller with `s` :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be helpful.

Edit file `controllers/front/ProductController.php`, line `91` or find `Tools::displayError('Product not found')`, and change this for this:

`header("Location: /");`

Comment: do you mean to edit the override file or the core file ?

Comment: yes- i've tried it - it doesn't work ...it keeps showing me the page with no product .anything else ?